# Как сделать действие после анимации при hover?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, по анимации. [Вот тут демо](https://codepen.io/alexbelkevich/pen/oZdpwK).

```css
.calendar__squares {
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes calendar-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares {
  animation: calendar-animation 1s 2s;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-1 {
  animation: calendar-animation 1s 0.1s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-2 {
  animation: calendar-animation 1s 0.2s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-3 {
  animation: calendar-animation 1s 0.3s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-4 {
  animation: calendar-animation 1s 0.4s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-5 {
  animation: calendar-animation 1s 0.5s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-6 {
  animation: calendar-animation 1s 0.6s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-7 {
  animation: calendar-animation 1s 0.7s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-8 {
  animation: calendar-animation 1s 0.8s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-9 {
  animation: calendar-animation 1s 0.9s infinite;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="svg-calendar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="65px" height="64px" viewBox="0 0 65 64" enable-background="new 0 0 65 64" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <rect fill="none" width="65" height="64"/>
 <g>
  <path fill="#BD9131" d="M62,5H52V2c0-1.104-0.896-2-2-2s-2,0.896-2,2v3H35V2c0-1.104-0.896-2-2-2s-2,0.896-2,2v3H17V2
   c0-1.104-0.896-2-2-2c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2v3H3C1.345,5,0,6.32,0,7.95v53.099C0,62.679,1.345,64,3,64h59c1.657,0,3-1.321,3-2.951
   V7.95C65,6.32,63.657,5,62,5z M61,60H4V9h9v3c0,1.104,0.896,2,2,2c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2V9h14v3c0,1.104,0.896,2,2,2s2-0.896,2-2V9
   h13v3c0,1.104,0.896,2,2,2s2-0.896,2-2V9h9V60z"/>
  <rect x="13" id="calendar-square-1" class="calendar__squares" y="21" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="29" id="calendar-square-2" class="calendar__squares" y="21" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="44" id="calendar-square-3" class="calendar__squares" y="21" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="13" id="calendar-square-7" class="calendar__squares" y="45" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="29" id="calendar-square-8" class="calendar__squares" y="45" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="44" id="calendar-square-9" class="calendar__squares" y="45" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="13" id="calendar-square-4" class="calendar__squares" y="33" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="29" id="calendar-square-5" class="calendar__squares" y="33" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="44" id="calendar-square-6" class="calendar__squares" y="33" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

При наведении на календарь появляются квадраты. Вопросы такие:
1. Как показывать квадраты по новому кругу только после того, как они все отобразятся
2. Как выполнить какое-то действие (например, окрасить сам календарь в другой цвет) после того, как отвел мышь?

Comment: Думаю, без JS тут не обойтись.

Comment: А на JS можно пример?

Comment: Лучше JavaScript использовать. А еще проще jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вам не рекомендую делать цепочки анимаций при помощи CSS, так у вас будет целый ворох проблем с контролем их последовательности. Конкретно для данного случая я рекомендую вам организовать цепочку при помощи события `transitionend`.

```js
let outer = document.querySelector('.outer'),
    inner = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.inner'));
    
inner.forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
  item.addEventListener('transitionend', function() { // присвоим каждому квадрату слушателя на оконачание transition
    if (this.nextElementSibling) {
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('inner--shown'); // при наличии следующего
                                                             // элемента добавим ему класс,                                                                    // который будет менять                                                                          // непрозрачность квадрата
    } else {
      inner.forEach(function(item, index, arr) { // если следующий элемент для анимации
        item.classList.remove('inner--shown');   // отстутствует, то снимаем класс, добавляющий
      });                                        // непрозрасность, со всех элементов
      
      setTimeout(function() {                    // через 150 мс добавим класс и таким образом 
        arr[0].classList.add('inner--shown');    // запустим цепочку заново
      }, 150);
    }
  });
});

outer.addEventListener('mouseover', animateFirst);
outer.addEventListener('mouseout', deactivate);

function animateFirst() {                        // обработка наведения мышки на объект
  outer.classList.remove('outer--mouseout');
  inner[0].classList.add('inner--shown');
}

function deactivate() {                          // обработка отведения мышки от объекта
  inner.forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
    item.classList.remove('inner--shown')
  });
  
  outer.classList.add('outer--mouseout');
}
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-color .15s;
}

.outer:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
}

.inner--shown {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .15s;
}

.outer--mouseout {
  background-color: #c5e3ff;
}
```

```html
<div class=outer>
  <div class=inner></div>
  <div class=inner></div>
  <div class=inner></div>
  <div class=inner></div>
  <div class=inner></div>
  <div class=inner></div>
  <div class=inner></div>
  <div class=inner></div>
  <div class=inner></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Скажем так, первая часть решается банально. Делайте анимацию в 2 раза длинее, вторая часть просто ожидание. Будет создаваться впечатление, что выжидается момент, когда анимация завершится:

```css
.calendar__squares {
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes calendar-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares {
  animation: calendar-animation 2s 2s;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-1 {
  animation: calendar-animation 2s 0.1s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-2 {
  animation: calendar-animation 2s 0.2s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-3 {
  animation: calendar-animation 2s 0.3s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-4 {
  animation: calendar-animation 2s 0.4s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-5 {
  animation: calendar-animation 2s 0.5s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-6 {
  animation: calendar-animation 2s 0.6s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-7 {
  animation: calendar-animation 2s 0.7s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-8 {
  animation: calendar-animation 2s 0.8s infinite;
}
#svg-calendar:hover .calendar__squares#calendar-square-9 {
  animation: calendar-animation 2s 0.9s infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="svg-calendar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="65px" height="64px" viewBox="0 0 65 64" enable-background="new 0 0 65 64" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <rect fill="none" width="65" height="64"/>
 <g>
  <path fill="#BD9131" d="M62,5H52V2c0-1.104-0.896-2-2-2s-2,0.896-2,2v3H35V2c0-1.104-0.896-2-2-2s-2,0.896-2,2v3H17V2
   c0-1.104-0.896-2-2-2c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2v3H3C1.345,5,0,6.32,0,7.95v53.099C0,62.679,1.345,64,3,64h59c1.657,0,3-1.321,3-2.951
   V7.95C65,6.32,63.657,5,62,5z M61,60H4V9h9v3c0,1.104,0.896,2,2,2c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2V9h14v3c0,1.104,0.896,2,2,2s2-0.896,2-2V9
   h13v3c0,1.104,0.896,2,2,2s2-0.896,2-2V9h9V60z"/>
  <rect x="13" id="calendar-square-1" class="calendar__squares" y="21" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="29" id="calendar-square-2" class="calendar__squares" y="21" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="44" id="calendar-square-3" class="calendar__squares" y="21" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="13" id="calendar-square-7" class="calendar__squares" y="45" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="29" id="calendar-square-8" class="calendar__squares" y="45" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="44" id="calendar-square-9" class="calendar__squares" y="45" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="13" id="calendar-square-4" class="calendar__squares" y="33" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="29" id="calendar-square-5" class="calendar__squares" y="33" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
  <rect x="44" id="calendar-square-6" class="calendar__squares" y="33" fill="#BD9131" width="8" height="7"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Второй вопрос легко решить с JQuery:

```
$( "#svg-calendar" ).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).addClass('afterhoverclass')
});
```

Остается только настроить цвет в классе `afterhoverclass` в CSS

Comment: ПО поводу первой части... Проблема не решилась...) Даже если ваш фрагмент выполнить)

Comment: @АлександрБелькевич Значит я вас не понял, опишите что вы хотели подробнее.

Comment: Ну вот появляются у нас эти квадратики. Появились. А теперь они должны все пропасть и после этого заново появиться :)